# How to create a function to add new record into a table? ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am not sure if using the create or replace function is the right way to do this but i am trying to figure out how to ONLY add record to the table when the count of employee ID where month of read date = month of sysdate is not more than 10.

I have a employee_read table using primary key, reading_ID, foreign key emp_id and an attribute of read_date.

The information i found online shows return value. but how do i add into table instead of return? is it do-able?

Thank you for your help!

> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION AddNewReadRecord
>
> (varEmpID IN NUMBER. varReadDate IN DATE, varWaterMeterID IN CHAR,
> varCuReading IN NUMBER, varPrevReading IN Number)
>
> RETURN
>
> BEGIN
>
> END

Comment: Doable - yes, as Tejash said. Should you do it? No; you should be using a **procedure** instead.

Comment: Yes, i will be using procedure instead of function. Tejash solution works and since it answers my question, it will be marked as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obviously add DML in the function but using `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION AddNewReadRecord
(varEmpID IN NUMBER. varReadDate IN DATE, varWaterMeterID IN CHAR, varCuReading IN NUMBER, varPrevReading IN Number)
RETURN number IS
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
Insert into your_table (...) -- column list
Select ... -- variable list
From your_table 
Where emp_id = varEmpID
And read_date = varReadDate
Group by emp_id
Having count(1) < 10;
Commit;
Return 1; -- add logic for return using exception
END;
/
```

Comment: Nice, i haven't read up on pragma yet. i should go research on it. thank you so much!

Comment: You can accept the answer if it solved your issue so that question is marked as resolved.